# How do I sync music on my iPad to my new iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, music

I have an iPad and recently purchased an iPhone.  I'd like to sync music currently on the iPad onto the phone. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How did you put music onto the iPad?

Comment: Principal of the IOS devices is to keep "copies" of your music.  There are hacky ways to move music off and onto the devices, but they will always be awkward.   Short answer.  Keep your music somewhere Itunes/Itunes match etc and then move it to the devices as needed.   Note there are workarounds, but staying within the designed way of use is going to simplify your life a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use iTunes. When you have all your music in iTunes, simply plug-in your iPhone to your Computer and sync all your music to your new iPhone.

1. Plug-In your iPad to your Computer
2. Open iTunes
3. Open the tab "on this iphone" 
   [image]
4. Now you can import all your iPad Music to your computer (if you have bought the music from iTunes)

Now you can plug-in your iPhone and sync all the music from your computer to your iPhone.

You can considering [iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/) for further solutions.